# How to add multiple charts inside one fragment with scroll view using mpandroidchart?

Tags: android, scrollview, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

As the title says I want to add multiple bar charts inside one tab fragment with a scroll view. I have added four charts inside one fragment but unable to scroll them. In future there will be more than four and anyhow I have to make the fragment scroll so that user can see multiple bar charts easily.

I have tried to make it scroll by adding  **android:fillViewport="true"** but it is not working.

I have been searching about this for hours and didn't get anything according to my requirement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

**Daily_layout** (fragment layout which contains multiple charts)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp" />

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
    android:id="@+id/chart1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp" />

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
    android:id="@+id/chart2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="320dp" />

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
    android:id="@+id/chart3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="480dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have got the ans for this

Answer (score -1):

1. Add `android:isScrollContainer="false"` in `ScrollView` and make it parent
2. Change height to *wrap_content* for the layouts which are inside the `ScrollView`

The layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    tools:context=".ReportFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.HIChartView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/bar_chart1"/>
        <com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.HIChartView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/bar_chart1"/>
        <com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.HIChartView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/bar_chart1"/>
        <com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.HIChartView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/bar_chart1"/>
        <com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.HIChartView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/bar_chart1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Consider formatting the answer correctly. formatting requires only tweaking the whitespaces, stackoverflow won't allow others to edit without modifying 6 non-whitespace characters.